# Where can I find the source code for javax.swing.BorderLayout class please?

Tags: java, swing

Where can I find the source code for `javax.swing.BorderLayout` class, please?

Comment: in `JDK_HOME\src.zip` or [BorderLayout.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.java.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the JDK that you dowloaded, in the src.zip file.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean java.awt.BorderLayout: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.java.html
or google.

Comment: Please never point to google because _this_ is the first result I got on google

Answer (score 0):

This has already been long before answered, but here I provide an 'once and for all' solution that beats the rest in elegance.

In my experience, this is the most convenient way of accessing any Java source. However, it's Eclipse-only.

After installing a Java Decompiler Eclipse plug-in (e.g. [*Eclipse Class Decompiler*](https://github.com/cnfree/Eclipse-Class-Decompiler), [*JD*](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-eclipse), etc.), you are almost there. Now, whenever you need source, press *F3* to go to its declaration, once the name has been highlighted.

Workflow:

- Just put `javax.swing.BorderLayout;` somewhere,
- select `BorderLayout`,
- press *F3*

*That's basically it.*

**Edit:** As pointed out by @cricket_007 the same goes for InteliJ. (w/ *Ctrl+B*)